# If $Z(G)$ is the only nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$, show $G/Z(G)$ is simple

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups, quotient-group

I was hoping to approach by saying if you mod out the only nontrivial normal subgroup, then the quotient group has no nontrivial normal subgroups. But maybe that's an oversimplification.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G/Z(G)$.
By Correspondence Theorem, $N=H/Z(G)$ where $Z(G)\lhd H \lhd G$.
By hypothesis, $H=Z(G)$ or $H=G$.
Hence $N=\{Z(G)\}$ or $N=G/Z(G)$.

In general,

> $N$ is a maximal normal subgroup of $G$ iff $G/N$ is simple.

Comment: From the material you are studying, which do you think gives the best treatment of the Correspondence Theorem, especially with regard to normal subgroups. Thanks. With regards,

Comment: @Andrew I think you may refer An Introduction of Theory of Groups by Rotman as it gives a complete proof for Correspondence Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p:G\rightarrow G/Z(G)$ the canonical projection and $N$ a proper normal subgroup of $G/Z(G)$, $p^{-1}(N)$ is a proper normal subgroup of $G$, it is $Z(G)$ by hypothesis this implies that $N=e$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have spent the last hour trying to decide which answer to accept. I had no basis to make a determination, since both are excellent in their own right and came in almost simultaneously. Although I never go to Meta, I read what I could to try to get some resolution. Best regards,